# ejabberd `Error: conflict` when trying to add new user that does not exist in PostgreSQL

Tags: ejabberd

Running ejabberd 21.01 (see below) on Debian 11.7 via `deb` packages. I started with the default Mnesia db got it working and registered my own account.
I decided later to move over to PostreSQL. It seemed successful, service was able to start (via `systemd`). However I can't add any new account with `ejabberdctl register`, it keeps saying:

`Error: conflict`

and nothing else.

I tried `ejabberdctl  check_account` to see if any account was indeed in the psql db, but it comes back false.

**Install Info**

```
apt info ejabberd
Package: ejabberd
Version: 21.01-2
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: Ejabberd Packaging Team <ejabberd@packages.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 9,372 kB
Provides: mqtt-broker, stun-server, turn-server, xmpp-server
```

Comment: If I revert back to the Mnesia database everything works well. I verifed the psql DB connection settings and its good with permissions checked too.

Comment: There were several versions numbered 21, there are several ways to install ejabberd that may include custom configurations, and there are several ways to configure ejabberd. If you don't provide precise details, surely you will not get precise response.